# How to create a LeaderBoard in Android Studio?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Main Activity code

I want to insert this

```
public void method() {
        name = LoginActivity.name;
        score = GameView.valueCurrent;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("score", score);
    }
```

And dont " myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('Marie', '4');");"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<Items> itemsList = new ArrayList<Items>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;

    try {

        //Create a Database if doesnt exist otherwise Open It

        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("leaderboard", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        //Create table in database if it doesnt exist allready

        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (name TEXT, score TEXT);");

        //Select all rows from the table

        Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scores", null);

        //If there are no rows (data) then insert some in the table

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
```

/*** In this case i want to put the values of the Users that are playing my app

```
                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('Andy', '7');");
                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('Marie', '4');");
                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('George', '1');");
```

**//

```
            }

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {

        //Initialize and create a new adapter with layout named list found in activity_main layout

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemsList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Cursor cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scores", null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                //read all rows from the database and add to the Items array

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                    Items items = new Items();

                    items.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                    items.setScore(cursor.getString(1));

                    itemsList.add(items);
                    cursor.moveToNext();


                }
            }

        //All done, so notify the adapter to populate the list using the Items Array

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

CustomListAdapter code

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private  Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Items> itemsItems;



public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<Items> itemsItems) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.itemsItems = itemsItems;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemsItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return itemsItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View scoreView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if (scoreView == null) {

        scoreView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) scoreView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.score = (TextView) scoreView.findViewById(R.id.score);

        scoreView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) scoreView.getTag();
    }

    final Items m = itemsItems.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(m.getName());
    holder.score.setText(m.getScore());

    return scoreView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView name;
    TextView score;

}

}
```

Items Code

```
public class Items {

private String name, score;

public Items() {
}

public Items(String name, String score) {

    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

}
```

Couple of more things.

How to show the current Leaderboard using this code of Database?

I dont know how to use on that.

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Play: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards

Create Google Play Game In Developer Console

1)Add the BaseGameUtils SDK from here https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

2) In app gradle:
 `dependencies {
     compile 'compile project(':BaseGameUtils')'
      }`

3) Update Score:  `Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, LEADERBOARD_ID, 1337);`

4)
Display Leaderboard: `startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
        LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);`

Make sure you successfully connect to googleApiClient/Google Play Games Services

Comment: I get an error : Project 'app'not found in root project 'MyAPP'.

Comment: Waiting for your comment

Comment: Your not using Google Play games, your trying to create your own leaderboard, maybe try using Parse-Server if you want to do it that way.